# Writing more than reading on socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

Is there a way to sample a video stream across an IP socket?

Could I have a server write images of a fixed size to a socket and have a client read only the most recent image from the socket, dropping frames as necessary?

TCP can be modeled as a queue, so there would be problems if the queue grows in length due to the number of writes outweighing the number of reads, right?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this very kind of problem when reading from a socket,on ubuntu, where ubuntu buffers UDP messages.

The easiest fix was to read in a loop, until the socket returned 0 bytes, then only process the data from the last successful read

On an embedded system, after about 2 days, there would be as much as 10 minutes of GPS data queued.

reading in a short loop into a buffer, until recv() returned 0 bytes, then using the results from the last successful read fixed the problem

I never did find a way to tell ubuntu to not buffer incoming UDP packets

Comment: Note: I initialized the socket as non-blocking so a read when no data was available would not hang, waiting for data

Comment: if your OS does not queue/buffer the video (which should be UDP protocol) packets, then reading will always return the last full video packet

Comment: Would you recommend UDP for this?